# Automatic layout for directed acyclic k-partite graph

Tags: graph, cytoscape

I have a directed, acylcic, k-partite graph which I want to layout in what seems the most intuitive way:

1. Each row of nodes corresponds to a partition, and they go with the flow of the graph.
2. The order of the nodes in each row is such that minimizes the number of crossing edges. Making the graph easier to read.

I would like to use cytoscape for this. Is this functionality already available? And if not, is it simple to program or is there some hack around it?

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
a
|\
v v
1 2
|
v
A
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes ... a fairly straightforward thing.

I created a graph just like yours in Cytoscape, and used Style to set the edge attributes to show arrows (for convenience).

I then used the yFiles Hierarchical Layout and got exactly your picture.

Note that there is a Hierarchical Layout that comes under the Layout menu pre-installed with Cytoscape 3.6. THAT'S NOT THE LAYOUT I MEAN ... because it doesn't honor directed links.

To get the yFiles version, click the "Install yFiles" submenu under the Layout menu, and then install and use the yFiles layouts.

[image]